# Drawing Pool table Pockets using OPENGL GLUT

Tags: opengl

As the title says really, I have drawn the rest of the table just having trouble drawing the pockets..

```
#pragma region Table Drawing Code

void drawTable()
{

glBegin(GL_QUADS); // RIGHT
glNormal3f(0,0,1);
glColor3d(0.5,0.35,0.05);
glVertex3f(m_TableX, 0.0f, m_TableWidth); //bottom left
glVertex3f(m_TableLength, 0.0f, m_TableWidth);//bottom right
glVertex3f(m_TableLength, 0.0f, m_TableWidth);//top right
glVertex3f(m_TableX, 0.0f, m_TableWidth); //top left        
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_QUADS); //BACK
glNormal3f(1,0,0);
glColor3d(0.5,0.35,0.05);
glVertex3f(m_TableLength, 0.0f,  m_TableWidth);
glVertex3f(m_TableLength, 0.0f, m_TableZ);
glVertex3f(m_TableLength, 0.0f, m_TableZ);
glVertex3f(m_TableLength, 0.0f, m_TableWidth);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_QUADS); //FRONT
glNormal3f(-1,0,0);
glColor3d(0.5,0.35,0.05);
glVertex3f(m_TableX, 0.0f, m_TableZ);
glVertex3f(m_TableX, 0.0f, m_TableWidth);
glVertex3f(m_TableX, 0.0f, m_TableWidth);
glVertex3f(m_TableX, 0.0f, m_TableZ);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_QUADS); //lEFT
glNormal3f(0,0,-1);
glColor3d(0.5,0.35,0.05);
glVertex3f(m_TableX, 0.0f, m_TableZ);
glVertex3f(m_TableLength, 0.0f, m_TableZ);
glVertex3f(m_TableX, 0.0f, m_TableZ);
glVertex3f(m_TableLength, 0.0f, m_TableZ);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_QUADS); //BOTTOM
glNormal3f(0,-1,0);
glColor3d(0.5,0.35,0.05);
glVertex3f(m_TableX, -0.001f,  m_TableWidth);
glVertex3f(m_TableLength, -0.001f,  m_TableWidth);
glVertex3f(m_TableLength, -0.001f, m_TableZ); 
glVertex3f(m_TableX, -0.001f, m_TableZ);
glEnd();


}

#pragma endregion
```

I am new to OpenGL so I'm not sure what to use to get the curve that is connected to the cushions and the hole in the table for the ball to drop.

Comment: Screenshots of what you have, what you expect, etc.

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/61783705@N06/5619348261/in/photostream 

I am new user so I am unable to post a screenshot. I want to be able to get a curve where the gaps in the table are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using gluPartialDisk to draw a "C" shape for the corner of the pocket
for example

void disk()
{

gluPartialDisk(gluNewQuadric(),1, 1.2, 10, 1, 0.0, -180);
}

then declare disk(); in your draw method