# how to draw pool table pockets opengl c++

Tags: c++, opengl

hey
i am creating a pool table simulator in opengl written in c++
i have the basic table drawn but now i need to add some pockets
i want the pockets to be a basic curve like a C shape
im not quite sure how to do this
i have experimented with trianglefan but iv had no luck
can anyone help please?

also i must add this is part of a university project therefore i will only be using the core opengl and c++....no other tools
thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing Pool table Pockets using OPENGL GLUT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667743/drawing-pool-table-pockets-using-opengl-glut)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to glu.lib?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Library
http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/glu.htm

That would easily make cylinders or NURBS curves for the pockets.  Sample use of it is here: http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=18

There is also lots of code from the "Graphics Gems" series available - you can dig through the early books for something suitable if GLU isn't an option.
http://www.graphicsgems.org/

Comment: thanks for this info it was helpful..i have been playing around with gluPartialDisk and now i have a flat curve "C" shape...now i was just wondering how i would create the rest of the pocket..almost like a cylinder with no top on for the ball to fall into..could you suggest anything from the glu library?  thanks in advance it's much appreciated!!!

Comment: gluCylinder - http://www.talisman.org/opengl-1.1/Reference/gluCylinder.html  -- by default they are open on top and bottom.

Answer (score 4):

When I use OpenGL, I usually build the models in something like Blender.

Blender is free and allows export to WaveFront obj - an easy format to read in to your program.  Or you can use the simple text WaveFront obj with a little scripted editing will produce a list of vertices that you can use in arrays for vertex buffer objects.

I couldn't imagine trying to build objects for a 3D scene using only discrete values and discrete math like (I think?) you're describing.

Comment: +1; It would be more trouble than it's worth to procedurally generate pool table geometry.  On the other hand, learning a tool like Blender and writing a simple importer will save you a tremendous amount of time on future projects.

Comment: thanks for the help but its a project for uni so we have to procedurally produce it...im just having trouble creating a curved pocket....iv just looked at that Blender and it looks great to use otherwise though! thanks for that info

Comment: @DK10: And now you learned why you need to mention school projects up front, so people can try to give you suggestions within the tools you're allowed to use instead of recommending the best tool they know.

Comment: yeah sorry about that...i'm new to the forum :) i know for future questions now though thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Start with a cube and slice off the bottom corners. Refine as necessary.